# Selling Ebooks in android using paypal option?

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, in-app-billing

My app is basically supposed to sell ebooks and need to distribute via Android Market. For payment options, I would like to use PayPal. So, straight to the point, am I allowed to use paypal as payment option for digital goods(in my case Ebooks)? I had googled for it a while. But nothing worth referencing came up to me.

I also read through Android Market terms and didn't quite get it whether they allow such option for in-app billing. All I see from their docs is referring to Google Checkout. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Well, just for information, I refer to http://www.google.com/mobile/android/market-tos.html .

---

Just to keep up, http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages  this link may well more specific to my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to be careful - the [TOS of the Android Market](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages) generally require you to use Google's payment processing options to charge users (see "Paid and Free Applications").

That said, they name two exceptions, one of which seems to apply in your case - "Where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g. buying songs that can be played on other music players)". If your app sells ebooks in the form of standard files (like epub or pdf), you should be in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can sell digital content using paypal via your app - however I don't think you can use Google's In-App Purchasing system - that has to go through the Market Place, and is linked to a Google Checkout account.
So you'd need a separate delivery and authentication system.

Comment: Keep in mind that not using Android's purchasing system is a violation of the TOS for an app.

Comment: @FunkTheMonk, thz for ur ans. For sure, I will not be using Google's In-App Purchasing system. I do have my auth and delivery system in place. Just the processing payment is a big headache. I don't want to violate any TOS of Android Market as well. Have you seen any app did that? Or any reference that support your answer?

Comment: @EboMike, can point me to the portion of TOS where they stated about **not using Android's purchasing system is a violation of the TOS for an app**. I ran through Android Market Terms so many times(well, at least 3 times). I still didn't find that discrete portion.

Comment: @PH7: http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages - Developers charging for applications and downloads from Android Market must do so by using an authorized Payment Processor. Developers offering additional content, goods, or services for an application downloaded from Android Market must offer an authorized Payment Processor as the payment option.

Comment: @EboMike, thz for ur prompt reply. So, **an authorized Payment Processor** they are referring is **Android Market In-app Billing with google checkout?**

But I do see two exceptions as well. My situation(selling ebooks) may well fall into second point. What do you think?

Comment: They recently changed the wording, this is actually the first time I'm seeing those two points, and if your ebooks are in a standard format (like epub or pdf), then I would think it's safe to say the second point applies in your case.

Comment: @EboMike, why not you just make ur suggestions as an answer. That could well benefit someone. :)